# ApiPlatform - implement authorization based on apiplatform filters

Tags: symfony, filter, authorization, api-platform.com, symfony4-voter

I'm using `ApiPlatform` and `Symfony5`

I placed a filter on the `User` entity to sort them by a boolean value of the class named `$expose`

Use case:

- For the `/users?expose=true` route `ROLE_USER` can get list of every `user` with filter `$expose` set to `true`
- For the `/users/` route `ROLE_ADMIN` can get list of every `user` no matter what

Here is my `User` class:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes={
 *          "normalization_context"={"groups"={"user:read", "user:list"}},
 *          "order"={"somefield.value": "ASC"}
 *     },
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "mehtod"="GET",
 *              "security"="is_granted('LIST', object)",
 *              "normalization_context"={"groups"={"user:list"}},
 *          }
 *     }
 * )
 * @ApiFilter(ExistsFilter::class, properties={"expose"})
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={
 *     "somefield.name": "exact"
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
```

I implement my authorization rules through `UserVoter`:

```
protected function supports($attribute, $subject): bool
    {
        return parent::supports($attribute, $subject) &&
            ($subject instanceof User ||
                $this->arrayOf($subject, User::class)  ||
                (is_a($subject, Paginator::class) &&
                    $this->arrayOf($subject->getQuery()->getResult(), User::class))
            );
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token): bool
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $token->getUser();

        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->accessDecisionManager->decide($token, [GenericRoles::ROLE_ADMIN])) {
            return true;
        }

        switch ($attribute) {
            case Actions::LIST:
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

To recover the list of  `User` I recover the paginator object passed through the `LIST` attribute and make sure the object inside the request result are of type `User`.
This part have been tested and work properly.

Now my issue come from the fact that both those route are essentialy the same to my `voter`, so my authorization rules implemented through it apply to them both.

What I would like to do would be to tell my voter that both request are different (which I thought I could do as I recover a `Paginator` object but doesn't seem possible) so I can treat them separately in the same switch case.

So far I havn't found a way to implement it

Is there a way to implement this kind of rules ?

Or is there another way to implement this kind of authorization ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with ordinary users and admin users using the same request `/users/` but getting different results,
[this docs page](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/#example) describes a way to make the result of GET collection operations depend on the user that is logged in. I adapted it for your question:

```
<?php
// api/src/Doctrine/CurrentUserExtension.php

namespace App\Doctrine;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Extension\QueryCollectionExtensionInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;
use App\Entity\Offer;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

final class CurrentUserExtension implements QueryCollectionExtensionInterface
{
    private $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function applyToCollection(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null): void
    {
        if (User::class !== $resourceClass || $this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            return;
        }

        $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
        $queryBuilder->andWhere("$rootAlias.expose = true");
    }
}
```

BTW, any users that do not have ROLE_ADMIN will get the filtered result, ROLE_USER is not required.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to stick with your use case that requires users with ROLE_USER to use /users?expose=true you can make a custom CollectionDataProvider that throws a FilterValidationException:

```
<?php

namespace App\DataProvider;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\ContextAwareCollectionDataProviderInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\CollectionDataProviderInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\RestrictedDataProviderInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Exception\FilterValidationException;
use App\Entity\User;

class UserCollectionDataProvider implements ContextAwareCollectionDataProviderInterface, RestrictedDataProviderInterface
{
    /** @var CollectionDataProviderInterface */
    private $dataProvider;

    private $security;

    /**
     * @param CollectionDataProviderInterface $dataProvider The built-in orm CollectionDataProvider of API Platform
     */
    public function __construct(CollectionDataProviderInterface $dataProvider, Security $security)
    {
        $this->dataProvider = $dataProvider;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supports(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return User::class === $resourceClass;
    }

    /** throws FilterValidationException */
    private function validateFilters($context)
    {
    if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            // Allow any filters, including no filters
            return;
        }
        if (!$this->security->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            throw new \LogicException('No use case has been defined for this situation');
        }

        $errorList = [];
        if (!isset($context["filters"]["expose"]) ||
            $context["filters"]["expose"] !== "true" && $context["filters"]["expose"] !== '1'
        ) {
            $errorList[] = 'expose=true filter is required.'
            throw new FilterValidationException($errorList);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @throws FilterValidationException;
     */
    public function getCollection(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): array
    {
        $this->validateFilters($context);

        return $this->dataProvider->getCollection($resourceClass, $operationName, $context);
    }
```

You do need to add the following to api/config/services.yaml:

```
'App\DataProvider\UserCollectionDataProvider':
    arguments:
        $dataProvider: '@api_platform.doctrine.orm.default.collection_data_provider'
```

BTW, to filter by a boolean one usually uses a BooleanFilter:

```
 * @ApiFilter(BooleanFilter::class, properties={"expose"})
```

This is relevant because users with ROLE_ADMIN may try to filter by expose=false. BTW, If $expose is nullable you need to test what happens with Users that have $expose set to null

**WARNING: Be aware that your security will fail silently, allowing all users access to all User entities, if the property $expose is no longer mapped or if the name of the property $expose is changed but in the UserCollectionDataProvider it is not or the Filter spec it is not!**